# Youtube Player API doesn't work in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, youtube-api

In normal html file, I use below code and it's working great.

```
var youtube;
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "youtube" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3",
             "ytpC", "1", "1", "8", "expressInstall.swf", null, params, atts);

.
.

 youtube.loadVideoById(link);
```

But when I moved this html into android phonegap environment, then it gives 'cannot call loadVideoById method of undefined!'

What is the exact problem?
What can I do to get success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is not supported and is not working on Android and ios (in case you plan to deploy on ios later on)

When you mentioned that it gives **cannot call loadVideoById method of undefined!**,
it is because you are using Flash API
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

Try using the iFrame API so it will use HTML5 instead
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference